# In single apk can i use more than 1 banner with 1 unitId?

Tags: admob, google-ads-api

I have a application with a ads. And i have a 1 banner ads. Can i use same unit id for use more than 1 banner only ? Like if i want use 3 banner should i take 3 diffrent banner id or same is working well too ? I googled it but cant found any document or same question as i asked thats why i want to ask in here .If i can use then i will put two or three ads with same id. And is it effecting money to get ? I just need informations about it. Thanks for helps :)

```
secondBanner = BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.banner,
      adUnitId: "MyBannerId",
      listener: BannerAdListener(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        setState(() {
          secondBannerLoaded = true;
        });
        print("Banner AD LOADED!!!!!!!!!!!");
      }, onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
        print("Banner AD ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!!!!!");
        inspect(error);

        ad.dispose();
      }),
      request: AdRequest(),
    );
    bannerAd = BannerAd(
      size: AdSize.banner,
      adUnitId: "MyBannerId",
      listener: BannerAdListener(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        setState(() {
          isLoaded = true;
        });
        print("Banner AD LOADED!!!!!!!!!!!");
      }, onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
        print("Banner AD ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!!!!!");
        inspect(error);

        ad.dispose();
      }),
      request: AdRequest(),
    );
    bannerAd!.load();
    secondBanner!.load();
```

Comment: You can use as many ads you would like to show with a single Ad-Unit Id, but it is better to use multiple for each screen/case for better reporting purposes. A single ad unit id will not give appropriate analytics/reports as to which part of the app is performing well, etc.